# How Do You Practically Calculate Common Percentages?

Tags: arithmetic

I was wondering if there is any quick way of calculating some common percentages such as $15\%$, $25\%$, $50\%$, $75\%$, $90\%$ etc.

The best think I could come up with is just simplifying the fraction they represent. So for $75%$, which is $\frac{3}{4}$, you just multiply by $3$ and divide by $4$. Is this the method some advanced mathematicians also use for quick, mental calculations? Or is there a better way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some mental arithmetic calculations are psychologically easier than others: a few years ago people discussed $75\%$ of $4$ being $3$ as an easy calculation, while $4\%$ of $75$ took longer despite multiplication being commutative.

Comment: @Henry I don't think that the fact that one of these is easier than the other has much to do with psychology. It's just easier to work with $3/4$ than with $4/100$.

Comment: @EthanBolker but it is just multiplication with $75\times4 = 4\times 75$.  The psychology comes from seeing $75\%$ and thinking $\frac34$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10% is easy, just divide by 10, in other words shift the decimal point.  Half of the result gives you 5%, add them and that's 15%.

50%, just divide by 2.

25%, divide by 4 either in one step, or by 2 then by 2 again.

75%, divide by 2 to get 50%, divide by 2 again to get 25%, add those two results.

90%, easy to find 10%, then subtract from the original.

Comment: This is just the thing I needed, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can just multiply using decimals. For example, if you want to find the $25\%$ of 70, you can just multiply
$$70 \cdot 0,25 = 17,5$$
In general, to find the $a \%$ of $x$ just do
$$x \cdot 0,a$$

Comment: I think decimal multiplication is much useful for arbitrary percentages such as $29\%$. For simple ones such as $20\%$ they seem needless.